# XOR outputs one because of propagaton delay in (basic) counter (FPGA)

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, xor

I have a basic counter example, counter is 6-bits wide.

```
reg[5:0] currcounterval_reg;
always @(posedge clk_g0)
    currcounterval_reg <= currcounterval_reg+ 1'b1;
```

My constraints
Clock is running at 83 Mhz 912ns period) on Virtex 7 chip.  The counter has no reset and the output is connected to board pins. When I run the circuit, I see switching in the signals as shown in the attached (hardware run) o/p. In the attached screenshot, if you look at the counter, after 7(seven), I should get '8'...but it first switches to '12'  as bit-2 goes to zero later than the others. I have an xor gate downstream where I compare o/p of two counters. How to I avoid getting into this problem?

Whatever I do for constraining, it doesn't go away. Please help me with some strategies to remove the switching.

Please feel free to ask me if you have more questions.

You can find a my waveform here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5OqF.png

Thanks.

Comment: How are you using the output of the downstream XOR?  Is the output of it sampled by the same clock which is driving your counters?

Comment: XOR output is tied to fpga pin, for monitoring purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that it is an improper constraint issue. But try wiring a synchronous counter explicitly to solve the issue.

```
    reg[5:0] counter;
    always @(posedge clk_g0)
    begin
        counter[0] <= ~counter[0] ;
        counter[1] <= (counter[0]    ) ? ~counter[1] : counter[1];
        counter[2] <= (&counter[1:0] ) ? ~counter[2] : counter[2];
        counter[3] <= (&counter[2:0] ) ? ~counter[3] : counter[3];
        counter[4] <= (&counter[3:0] ) ? ~counter[4] : counter[4];
        counter[5] <= (&counter[4:0] ) ? ~counter[5] : counter[5];
    end
```

Comment: I am going try this now. Today, I tried instantiating counter primitive, COUNTER_LOAD_MACRO. I still get the same result, even at 1Mhz. I believe, all I can do it capture the output into another register (1 clock cycle delay) and then do XOR on it.  What would be a good delay constaint for the second flop, if I want to run even at 150Mhz.

Comment: No, I don't think that will help. You need a flip-flop _after_ the XOR gate...see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the XOR output synchronous. The XOR output should go to the D input of a FF that is clocked on the same rising edge that increments the counters. Bring the Q output of the FF to an FPGA pin rather than the XOR output.

You shouldn't try to match the combinational logic delays and routing delays of the two counters. The delay paths from two counters to your XOR gates will almost certainly be different so a fast XOR (like on a Virtex 7) will generate glitches. In a good synchronous design that doesn't matter, because you only care that the combinational logic outputs are valid before the next clock edge.

Comment: I agree with you. I told about the XOR only for context. The problem is that o/p of counter registers are settling rather late. Although I didn't show it in the image, sometimes the register o/p takes more than a clock cycle to settle. And I don't have any timing violations.  I am pretty sure its a constraint issue...just not sure how to specify it. The constraint between counter and its combinational logic I believe need not be specified.

Comment: OK, it's important to ask a question accurately. Now, looking carefully at your waveforms it looks like the settling time is not a clock cycle it is _exactly_ one simulation time unit. Also, the clock signal does not seem to behave properly...the pulse width is changing. I am suspicious that your `timespec` may be using a resolution that is too coarse. Can you tell us what your `timespec` is for the testbench? I'm assuming these are simulation results.

Comment: Sorry for the cofusion. My apologies. All of this was done on actual FPGA...not simulation. So I am not sure if timespec matters.

Comment: Are you using ChipScope then? Is there some parameter that can make it sample more often?

Comment: yes. I am using chipscope. I run design clock t 70 MHz. The sampling frequency is between 240 Mhz and 300Mhz. I believe that should be sufficient. Also, since the XOR is going high downstream, I believe it means the signals are settling late. Btw, what (typical) parameters should one use for input and o/p port delays?